# Detecting if EC2 instances are part of a CloudFormation via CloudWatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

When CloudWatch Events come in with notifications about the creation of new EC2 instances, what's the simplest way to detect if that instance is part of a CloudFormation stack?

My first approach was to call [`DescribeInstances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) on the instance to look for the `aws:cloudformation:stack-id` tag, but apparently there is a delay before that tag is added, so this is getting messy.

Should I just query the CloudFormation API directly instead?  When I see a CloudWatch Event about a new EC2 instance, is there an ordering guarantee that this EC2 instance will show up as a member if I call the CloudFormation API?

Comment: Tough question. What about restricting CloudFormation to use a specific IAM rule? And check for the role within the event?

Comment: Describing the stack resources does not work as long as the stack update is in progress, as far as I remember.

Comment: In this case I don't have any control over the CloudFormation IAM role.  I'm using STS to monitor a foreign AWS account.

Comment: If the stack update is in progress, then maybe I can do a polling loop until it is done, and then query the stack resources (a la https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-testkit/blob/master/libraries/provision/generate_pools_json_from_aws.py#L109-L139)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in [wjordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518355/wjordan)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543352/detecting-if-ec2-instances-are-part-of-a-cloudformation-via-cloudwatch-events#comment70327786_41554583) worked for me and seems to be reliable and free of any race conditions.

Solution: as soon as an instance is detected on Cloudwatch Event stream, call `DescribeStackResources(..)` against the cloudformation API and pass `{PhysicalResourceId: instanceId}`.  It will return the stack id that the instance is part of, or an empty result if it's not part of any cloudformation stacks.

I implemented it in Go and put it on github in the [tleyden/awsutil](https://github.com/tleyden/awsutil/blob/2feaa00723e501e88cc6a3b4a479290804931f82/cloudformation.go#L114-L149) repo.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the EC2 instance ID returned in a CloudWatch Event corresponds to an instance in the running CloudFormation stack, you can call the [`DescribeStackResources`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html) API with the current stack ID as the [`StackName` request parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html#API_DescribeStackResources_RequestParameters). If any `StackResource` is returned with a `PhysicalResourceId` matching the EC2 Instance ID returned by the event, then you can be sure that the event corresponds to the instance in the current stack.

Here's a complete, working example:

[image: Launch Stack]

```
Description: Run a Lambda function when the EC2 instance is created using a CloudWatch Event.
Mappings:
  # amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20161221-x86_64-gp2
  RegionMap:
    us-east-1:
      "64": "ami-9be6f38c"
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: m3.medium
    AllowedValues: [m3.medium, m3.large, m3.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, c3.large,
      c3.xlarge, c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge, c3.8xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge,
      r3.8xlarge, i2.xlarge, i2.2xlarge, i2.4xlarge, i2.8xlarge]
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid instance type.
Resources:
  WebServer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: EventLambdaPermission
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [ RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", 64]
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
  EventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: EventRule
      EventPattern:
        source: ["aws.ec2"]
        detail-type: ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"]
        detail:
          state: [pending]
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
      - Arn: !GetAtt EC2StateChange.Arn
        Id: TargetFunction
  EC2StateChange:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Sends a Wait Condition signal to Handle when an EC2 Instance State-change from this stack is received.
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            var instanceId = event.detail['instance-id'];
            var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
            cloudformation.describeStackResources({StackName: '${AWS::StackId}'}).promise().then((stackData)=>{
              if (stackData.StackResources.find((stack)=> stack.PhysicalResourceId == instanceId)) {
                finish(context, {
                  "Status" : "SUCCESS",
                  "UniqueId" : "InstanceId",
                  "Data" : instanceId,
                  "Reason" : ""
                });
              } else {
                console.log("Instance ID not found in this stack");
                context.done();
              }
            }).catch((e)=>{
              console.log("Error:\n",JSON.stringify(e));
              finish(context, {
                "Status" : "FAILED",
                "UniqueId" : "InstanceId",
                "Data" : instanceId,
                "Reason" : e.message
              });
            });
          };
          function finish(context, response) {
            responseBody = JSON.stringify(response);
            var https = require("https");
            var url = require("url");
            var parsedUrl = url.parse('${Handle}');
            var options = {
                hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
                port: 443,
                path: parsedUrl.path,
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "",
                    "content-length": responseBody.length
                }
            };
            console.log("Options:\n", JSON.stringify(options));
            var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
                console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
                console.log("Status message: " + response.statusMessage);
                console.log("Done!");
                context.done();
            });
            request.on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("send(..) failed executing https.request(..): " + error);
                context.done();
            });
            request.write(responseBody);
            request.end();
          }
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  EventLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref EC2StateChange
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRule.Arn
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: EC2Policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - 'cloudformation:DescribeStackResources'
              Resource: ['*']
  Handle:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
  Wait:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
    Properties:
      Handle: !Ref Handle
      Timeout: 300
Outputs:
  Result:
    Value: !GetAtt Wait.Data
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't completely clear. I'm tapping into the CloudWatch Event stream of an AWS account that I don't have any control over, and currently I'm just observing all of the EC2 instance state changes, but not any CloudFormation events.  When I see a new EC2 instance created (in the pending or running state), I want to determine if it's part of a CloudFormation or not, since my code will behave differently.  Looks like your solution assumes I am launching the CloudFormation and know the stack id, but I don't.  One option is to add CloudFormation events to CloudWatch event stream.

Comment: As an alternative, you can pass `{PhysicalResourceId: instanceId}` to `describeStackResources` If you want to know if the instance is a part of _any_ CloudFormation stack, not necessarily the current one. However, if you really do have _no_ control over the AWS account you're interested in, and can really do nothing but watch the CloudWatch event stream, I don't think _any_ option would work, since you would be unable to call any AWS API reading the other account's resources in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  I have no control over how CloudFormation stacks are launched and what goes into CloudFormation template, however I have read-only API access into EC2 and CloudFormation API to inspect state.  If I see an ec2 instance on CWE and call `describeStackResources ` w/ `{PhysicalResourceId: instanceId}`, will that always return or might I need to do a polling loop?  In either case, seems like a useful tip!  Thank you!